# Roo GWT. How to filter scaffold generated ListView

Tags: gwt, spring-roo

Roo generates a ListView for each entity, and it works great if you want to view the entire table, but how can we modify the generated ListViews to work off of some type of search criteria, for example a couple combo boxes and a "Search" button? Say I wanted to only find records modified after a certain date.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about using GWT, but you could create a finder for your entity in Roo using `finder add --finderName`. Roo will then add this to the side menu and allow you to enter anything you are filtering on.

For your case it would be something like:

`finder add --finderName findAllEntitiesWhereModifiedDataLargerThan`